# Recomendation for automated rotation of a JSON keyring?

Tags: key-management, aws, node.js

I have a Sailsjs app that is configured to encrypt model attributes with sensitive information. This seems to use bcrypt, under the hood and leverages [a JSON keyring in the configuration](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?key-rotation) (environmental variable might work too).

The docs imply that rotation requires me to SSH into each deployed instance and edit the keyring in configuration files (or at least do it once and save a new AMI for an EC2 launch configuration). Is there not a better-automated solution?

AWS KMS has an option to rotate keys annually, without any intervention on my part. Is there any sort of similar service for symmetric encryption in applications?

Forgive me if I'm not describing this well, I'm new to the devops side of things.

Comment: Unfortunately, product/service recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Have you tried https://devops.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/9104/recomendation-for-automated-rotation-of-a-json-keyring